# Can you early return with React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The React docs make it clear that [calling hooks conditionally will not work](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). [From the original React hooks presentation](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM?t=1938), the reason is because React uses the order you call hooks to inject the correct value.

I understand this, but now my question is whether or not it's okay to early return from within a function component with hooks.

So is something like this allowed?:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRouteMatch, Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function Component() {
  const { match } = useRouteMatch({ path: '/:some/:thing' });
  if (!match) return <Redirect to="/" />;

  const { some, thing } = match.params;
  const state = useSelector(stateSelector(some, thing));

  return <Blah {...state} />;
}
```

Technically, the `useSelector` hook is being called conditionally, however the order when they are called doesn't change between renders (even though it's possible that one less hook will be called).

If this isn't allowed can you explain *why* it isn't allowed and provide general alternative approaches to early returning in a function component with hooks?

Comment: You have an answer in your own question - it isn't allowed, because `React uses the order you call hooks to inject the correct value`. It actually might work in your case and the warning you will get will simply be a warning not the error. But you might fall into the error later, when you effectively forget whereabouts about this component and decide to add more hooks or re-arrange the conditional.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

React does not allow you to do an early return prior to other hooks. If a component executes fewer hooks than a previous render, you will get the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

React can't tell the difference between an early return before a hook call and a hook call that is conditional for some other reason. For instance, if you have 3 calls to `useState` and you sometimes return after the second one, React can't tell whether you returned after the second `useState` call or if you put a condition around the first or second `useState` call, so it can't reliably know whether or not it is returning the correct state for the two `useState` calls that **did** occur.

Here's an example that you can use to see this error in action (click the "Increment State 1" button twice to get the error):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [state1, setState1] = React.useState(1);
  if (state1 === 3) {
    return <div>State 1 is 3</div>;
  }
  const [state2, setState2] = React.useState(2);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>State 1: {state1}</div>
      <div>State 2: {state2}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setState1(state1 + 1)}>Increment State 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setState2(state2 + 1)}>Increment State 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Early return with hooks]

The alternative approach I would recommend is to separate the portion after the early return into its own component. Anything needed by the portion after the early return gets passed to the new component as props.

In the case of my example, it could look like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const AfterEarlyReturn = ({ state1, setState1 }) => {
  const [state2, setState2] = React.useState(2);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>State 1: {state1}</div>
      <div>State 2: {state2}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setState1(state1 + 1)}>Increment State 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setState2(state2 + 1)}>Increment State 2</button>
    </div>
  );
};
function App() {
  const [state1, setState1] = React.useState(1);
  if (state1 === 3) {
    return <div>State 1 is 3</div>;
  }
  return <AfterEarlyReturn state1={state1} setState1={setState1} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Early return with hooks]

Comment: this is a good idea but it's not clean enough so I had write [this HOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/with-valued-data) to make it cleaner

Comment: Totally super nitpicking but an early return *is* a conditional hook call.

Comment: @Evert I'm not sure what you are getting at. A return (early or otherwise) is not a hook call. It can result in a conditional hook call if a hook call occurs after the early return, but there is no hook call after the early return in my second example -- both branches just return React elements.

Comment: Sorry, it's a nitpick on your comment: `React can't tell the difference between an early return and a conditional hook call`. If there was a return before a hook call, that hook call _is_ conditional.

Comment: I thought the problem with conditional hook calls was that React matches them sequentially with its internal hook state. So if a conditional hook results in a difference sequence (say, an `if` statement around a hook call), then React wouldn't know how to match the calls up with it's internal state of hooks. If that's correct, then early returns wouldn't have that problem, because the hooks are always called in the same sequence during a render, and so would always match a previous sequence. Some of the later hooks might not get called, but I think React could have chosen to handle that.

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned, you can't run hooks conditionally inside component. But you can pass render function that might be considered as custom hook to other components and still have access to current scope. So instead of splitting your component use utility component like that:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const HooksHost = ({ children }) => children();

function App() {
  const [state1, setState1] = React.useState(1);

  if (state1 === 3) {
    return <div>State 1 is 3</div>;
  }

  return (
    <HooksHost>
      {/* should be named to pass lint rule that checks if it starts from 'use' then it is custom hook */}
      {function useHooks() {
        const [state2, setState2] = React.useState(2);
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <div>State 1: {state1}</div>
            <div>State 2: {state2}</div>
            <button onClick={() => setState1(state1 + 1)}>
              Increment State 1
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setState2(state2 + 1)}>
              Increment State 2
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </HooksHost>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```